# How to easy make resizable image that keeps aspect ratio at resize?

Tags: html, image, resize, aspect-ratio

I need to put in html page the image that will resize with keeping aspect ratio when browser border will change. Something like that:
[image]

I tried this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Resize</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style = "width: 100%;"><img src = "zast.jpg" style = "width: 100%;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the image resizes when width only changes, if I change height of window, just a scroll appears.
If I add height: 100% to both tags, then image resizes without keeping aspect ratio.
What could I do to achieve what I need?
I looking for some really easy way, like two - three tags. But if no such way, I would be glad to anything.

It can be not img tag. I could use anything (for example background of div or table or td)

Comment: This will surely help: http://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design/

Comment: Thank you. This is really helped. The minimal working thing is: `<center><img src = "zast.jpg" style = "max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;"></center>` make it as answer and I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the a great resource about whats you asking.

http://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design/

Comment: Just leave your solution here for more visibility as alternative way: `<div style = "background-image: url(zast_512.jpg); background-size: contain; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>` Hovewer, in IE6 image gets cropped.

Comment: @Kosmos thank you, by the way dont you think supporting IE6 is too much, I think Microsoft told that they will support it till April 2014, will search for the link, dont know if it was a rumour.

Comment: IE6 is old right. I told about this just as example. Real problems that in IE8 is the same, while that's the highest IE for Win XP and I not planning to drop it's support.